# AngularJS Symfony 2 auto generate css

Tags: css, angularjs, symfony

I'm working on angularJS application with symfony 2 .In the web folder i found css files renamed this way :

```
536fd4f_part_5.css
536fd4f_part_6.css
536fd4f_part_7.css
...
```

It's an automatically way to generate css files ? how can i configure my project to add others css files ?

Comment: are you using an assets manager like assetic ?

Comment: yes in my config.yml file i put assetic configuration, so what command i use to generate css  ?